# How to create an extension for UILabel, UITextView and UITextField

Tags: swift, uikit

I have the following code. How can I make it into one single extension?

```
extension UITextView {
    func setAccessibility(fontSize : UIFont.TextStyle) {
         self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
         self.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
     }
}

extension UITextField {
    func setAccessibility(fontSize : UIFont.TextStyle) {
         self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
         self.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
     }
}

extension UILabel {
    func setAccessibility(fontSize : UIFont.TextStyle) {
        self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        self.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}
```

Comment: @grow4gaurav, how would generics let the OP create an extension on 3 classes like that?

Comment: You can't considering that UILabel `font` property declaration is `UIFont!` while `UITextView` and `UITextField` are `UIFont?`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have fun!!!

```
extension UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting {

    func setAccessibility(fontSize : UIFont.TextStyle) {

        switch self {
        case let self as UILabel:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        case let self as UITextView:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        case let self as UITextField:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        default:
            break
        }
        adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
    }
}

let label = UILabel()
let field = UITextField()
let view = UITextView()

label.setAccessibility(fontSize: .body)
field.setAccessibility(fontSize: .body)
view.setAccessibility(fontSize: .body)
```

Comment: why there is need of if let multiple times although you are doing same thing  ?

Comment: Because you need access to the `font` property!

Comment: You can use this variant but it's not safety
`(self as? NSObject)?.setValue(UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize), forKey: "font")`

Comment: @Dmitry I would prefer using a switch instead of multiple if else if conditions `switch self {
        case let self as UILabel:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        case let self as UITextView:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        case let self as UITextField:
            self.font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
        default: break
        }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, it makes sense)

Answer (score 2):

A while back I stumbled upon something similar, but ended up finding the best solution, I'm posting this here. Make a protocol and add the method implementation in the protocol extension and confirm all the required classes to that extension:

```swift
protocol AccessibilitySettable: AnyObject {
    var font: UIFont? { get set }
    var adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory: Bool { get set }
    func setAccessibility(fontSize: UIFont.TextStyle)
}

extension AccessibilitySettable {
    func setAccessibility(fontSize: UIFont.TextStyle) {
         font = .preferredFont(forTextStyle: fontSize)
         adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
     }
}

extension UITextField: AccessibilitySettable { }
extension UITextView: AccessibilitySettable { }
```

Note: `UILabel` has unwrapped `font!` property instead of the optional hence it doesn't confirm to the same protocol.